# Pass object as a string for debugging in VSCode' launch.json file

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug my python module using the VSCode debugger. I prepare my `launch.json` file as below:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "type": "pwa-chrome",
              "request": "launch",
              "name": "Python: Current file",
              "url": "http://localhost:8081",
              "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "runtimeArgs": ["arg1", "arg2", '{"host":"https://x.xxx.xx.xxx/console","port":443,"selfSignedCert": false}', '{"auth": {"sec": "ccccccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-gggggggggg"}}', "args3"]
          }
      ]
}
```

But I believe this is not the right way to pass the objects `'{"host":"https://x.xxx.xx.xxx/console","port":443,"selfSignedCert": false}'` and `'{"auth": {"sec": "ccccccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-gggggggggg"}}'`.

I want to pass the object into the module as it is, ie., with the single quotes. Can someone help me with the right way to do that?

Comment: Since `launch.json` must be in [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) file, you can't use single quotes where JSON expects double quotes, therefore you can't do what you want. Why do you want them anyway? I think this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: …cont. If you want the strings to have embedded double quote characters, you can escape those characters like this: `"{\"host\":\"https://x.xxx.xx.xxx/console\",\"port\":443,\"selfSignedCert\": false}"` and `"{\"auth\": {\"sec\": \"ccccccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-gggggggggg\"}}"`

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. But just to let you know, this is how my program expects the inputs to be. And therefore I must pass it that way. Another way I can do it to process them after taking the input. Thanks a lot @martineau

Comment: The awkwardness is just an artifact of the fact that the settings are being stored in a JSON-format file.

Answer (score 0):

From [Debugging configurations for Python apps in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args):

> #### args
>
> Specifies arguments to pass to the Python program. Each element of the
> argument string that's separated by a space should be contained within
> quotes, for example:
>
> `"args": ["--quiet", "--norepeat", "--port", "1593"],`

It seems impossible to add `''` in the args.